# How should end-to-end acceptance tests divide a large feature into scenarios?

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing, gherkin, end-to-end, atdd

In his article [What's in a Story?](http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story/) Dan North makes a number of excellent points.  Three in particular are:

1. > #### The scenario title should say what’s different
   >
   > You should be able to line up the scenarios side by side, and describe how they differ using only the title.
2. > #### The scenario should be described in terms of Givens, Events and Outcomes
   >
   > This is the single most powerful behavioural shift I have seen in teams adopting BDD. Simply by getting the business users, the analysts, the testers and the developers to adopt this vocabulary of “given/when/then”, they discover that a world of ambiguity falls away.
   >
   > Not all scenarios are this simple. Some are best represented as a sequence of events, described as: *given [some context] when [I do something] then [this happens] when [I do another thing] then [this new thing happens]* and so on. An example is a wizard-style website, where you step through a sequence of screens to build up a complex data model. It is perfectly appropriate to intermingle sequences of events and outcomes, as long as you get into the habit of thinking in these terms.
3. > #### The story should be small enough to fit in an iteration
   >
   > There are no hard and fast rules about how you do this, as long as you break it down into demonstrable chunks. In general if there are more than about five or six scenarios, a story can probably be broken down by grouping similar scenarios together.

Now suppose that one is trying to describe end-to-end acceptance tests for some wizard-style feature (like he considered above).

- It's natural to define "scenarios" by how state differs at the outset of one's use of the wizard feature (indeed this would appear to fit with his points #1 and #2 above)—but surely it's inappropriate to enumerate every path through the wizard (from start to finish) in a fully serialised form to produce such independent scenarios?  Not only would that produce a great many scenarios, but each would comprise a great many steps (contrary to Dan's point #3)—and a lot of those steps would be duplicated between scenarios simply to reach the state at which they diverge!

  ```
  Scenario: Make a successful booking
    Given that I am at the booking form
    When I do A
    Then I see B
    When I do C
    Then I see D
    When I try to book
    Then I see a successful message

  Scenario: Attempt to book, no availability
    Given that I am at the booking form
    When I do A
    Then I see B
    When I do C
    Then I see D
    When I try to book
    Then I see no availability
  ```
- On the other hand, it'd be more efficient to define *one scenario* for *each possible state* at the start of *each decision branch* within the wizard feature—and the `When` "event" would simply be the single step that takes the feature on to the next decision branch.  However, doesn't this move the SUT down the stack, so we'd no longer be defining end-to-end acceptance tests but rather something of a lower order?  Moreover, it's much less natural to follow and understand the test criteria—which surely defeats the whole point of BDD?

  ```
  Scenario: Do first step
    Given that I am at the booking form
    When I do A
    Then I see B

  Scenario: Do second step
    Given that I see B
    When I do C
    Then I see D

  Scenario: Make a successful booking
    Given that I see D
    When I try to book
    Then I see a successful message

  Scenario: Attempt to book, no availability
    Given that I see D
    When I try to book
    Then I see no availability
  ```

  If going this route, it seems to me more correct to divide each decision branch into separate features; and then only those scenarios at each branch would be considered within a single feature—which only emphasises my point about the SUT having moved down the stack.
- Perhaps these end to end acceptance tests are too detailed, and the whole wizard should (at this stage) be treated more as a black box?  I'm not sure how this helps the customer to understand what they are commissioning, however—especially since the detailed steps of this feature are key to the acceptability of the whole system.

What is the most appropriate way of dividing such a feature into scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

The problems most of us have with wizards are to do with how we express things. When a feature explores 'how' something is done, it ends up being verbose. What we should concentrate on is why we are doing things.

If we think this way we could negate the problem entirely by encapsulating the whole wizard as one thing. For example:

```
Feature: Fill in my tax form

Scenario: Fill in my tax form
  When I fill in my tax form
  Then my tax form should be filled in
```

However thats probably to 'high' an abstraction for something as complex as this. To add more detail you have to divide the scenario up into parts and find a reason for filling in each part. Then you use the reason (the why) to write your scenarios.

If we go back to the tax form and pretend it contains just three parts (for simplicity): identity, income, expenses.

Now we can write things like:

```
Feature: Tax indentification
  As someoene who is taxed
  I need to provide proper indentification
  So I pay for my tax and not someone else's

Scenario: Provide indentification
  Given I am filling in my tax form
  When I provide indentification
  Then I should be asked about my income
```

We can explore sad paths with things like

```
  When I provide insufficient identification
  Then I should be asked for more indentification
```

etc.

When we have implemented that we should be able to write

```
Feature: Tax - provide income details
  ... 

Given I am filling in my tax form
And I have provided indentification
When I provide my income details
Then I should be asked about my expenses
```

and we can repeat the process about exploring sad paths. Notice that the Given can be implemented using the test functionality we created when implementing the identity stage.

The art of this is all about finding out why you complete each stage of the process and what names you give to the various states you arrive at as you make your journey through the process. Notice also that there is no mention of 'how' you do this stuff anywhere in the feature

Finally this is pretty much the second method you talked about, with additional emphasis on 'why' over 'how'. You can choose the level of abstraction (i.e. how many pieces you break this into) and you can control the naming. The language and the naming address your issues of readability, particularly if you take into account the extra context you can give from things like the name of the feature and its position in the file heirarchy.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the covering of all paths for each possible state is too detailed. BDD helps teams to specify collaboratively and to do a deliberate discovery. Therefore you should focus on key examples (http://gojko.net/2014/05/05/focus-on-key-examples/).

Your [automated tests have often several purposes](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-w6okC4IPPso/Twbz3W9xkqI/AAAAAAAAAA4/BFa7bWn5rww/s1600/testing-pyramid.png). The basis is build through unit tests that help you ensure that you build your product right. Acceptance tests take the next level and help you to build the right product.